# IBM MQ JMS not working after migration to Spring Boot 3 with com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client.jar 9.3

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-boot-3

I tried to call an Enterprise MQ in Spring Boot 2.5 using `javax.jms` MQ dependencies. The connection is being successfully made. Below is my `pom.xml` and code. I am using an App ID credentials to connect to the queue which I have set in the UserCredentialsProvider class.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code -

```java
    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        try {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(username);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(password);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter) {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(500);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
        jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
        return jmsTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsOperations jmsOperations(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(receiveTimeout);
   Connection c = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
   System.out.println(c.getMetaData()); //the connection is established successfully
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
```

Now, what I did was that I tried to migrate to Spring Boot 3.1.1. I had to change my MQ dependencies in POM to use `jakarta` in place of `javax` package. Below is my updated POM:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I updated the above code to use jakarta Connection Factory instead of JMS , but now I am getting MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED(2035) error.

What modifications do I have to perform in order for this to work in Spring Boot 3.1 with com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client.jar 9.3?

Comment: It is not clear what the actual version is of the com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar.  0.0.0.3 is not a valid version.  Can you please check the manifest of the original com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar for the version?

Comment: I did a test. for my spring boot 2.5 code , I updated the version of com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar from 0.0.0.3 till 9.2. It works fine but as soon as I update it to 9.3 , I start getting the same unauthorized error which I was getting using spring boot 3.1 !
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient

0.0.0.3 - 9.2 - works fine
>9.3 - gives unauthorized error.
So in stead of 0.0.0.3 you can refer any version which is < 9.3. It seems to work for those.

Comment: The MANIFEST.MF inside the 0.0.0.3 jar would tell you the actual version.

Comment: Here are the manifest details for 0.0.0.3 - 

Specification-Title: Java Message Service
Specification-Version: 2.0
Specification-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: IBM MQ classes for JMS and Java
Implementation-Version: 9.0.4.0 - p904-L171030.1

Comment: So that older version is really from 9.0.4 of MQ.

Comment: Thank you for the well written question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 9.3 the default for MQ authentication in Java and JMS classes changed from compatibility mode to MQCSP.  This is why you are now getting a 2035. To get the connection working again you need to switch back to compatibility mode.

There are a few methods to set it back to compatibility mode, two of them are:

1. Set the connection factory property `JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP` to `false`
2. Set the Java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication` to `N`.
   For example:

   - `System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication", "N")`
   - `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=N`

For more details see [Connection authentication with the Java client](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=authentication-connection-java-client).

---

9.3 breaking it likely means one of three things:

1. The queue manager uses a custom security exit to validate the username and password that expects compatibility mode.
2. The queue manager has `CONNAUTH` configured with `ADOPTCTX(NO)`.
3. The queue manager has no security in place and the queue manger just assumes the username you send is correct.

You can test if it is #3 by turning on compatibility mode and intentionally sending a incorrect password. If it works then you know it is #3.

You can test if it is #2 by turning off compatibility mode, sending the correct password and specifying `-Duser.name=username`, if this works then it is likely #2.

If both of the above fail then it is likely #1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great input ! Went with option 1 and it worked for me !

Comment: Thank you for the quick accept.   I added some extra information at the end about why it would have broken with 9.3.

Comment: One more follow up query to the above case is that my JMS health check actuator fires up after spring boot app is started and it gives unauthorized . But when I hit it using a test endpoint it works perfectly fine. I guess connection factory for actuator is not able to set those credentials while hitting the queue. My question is - is there any way we can disable the actuator for jms or pass credentials to the connection factory used by the actuator in the above code?

Comment: Is it setting `JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP`?

Comment: yes , I have added below code -      mqQueueConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);
For now, I have added 
management.health.jms.enabled=false, so it is not triggering the health check on startup :)